Overloading matrix multiplication as function composition
I played a bit around and wanted to try to overload the matrix multiplication operator for function composition.
Instead of writing:
f(g(x)) I would like (f @ g) to return a new function as the composition of f and g.
I am well aware that this most likely not a good idea for production code, but I want to understand what is going on.
The following code should work, but
import types

def compose(f, g):
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: f(g(*args, **kwargs))

def make_composable(f):
    f.__matmul__ = types.MethodType(compose, f)
    return f

@make_composable
def f(n):
    return 2 * n

@make_composable
def g(n):
    return 3 * n

assert (f.__matmul__(g)) (2) == f(g(2))

assert (f @ g) (2) == f(g(2))

in the last assert I get a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'function' and 'function'

I guess there is something wrong with how I monkey-patch the __matmul__ method which is not correctly accepted for the operator overloading?

Special methods need to be invoked on the class rather than the instance (see: special method lookup). However, the built-in function-type isn't subclassable, so you'd either need to create a custom callable type, or use something like forbiddenfruit to extend the built-in function-type.
